# How to exec quit command in the same channel in the perl

Tags: perl, libssh2

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH2;

#--
my $server='x.x.x.x';
my $user='xxxx';
my $passwd='xxxx';
#--
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();

print "Connecting to $server...\n";
$ssh2->connect($server) or die 'connect problem';

if( $ssh2->auth_password($user, $passwd)) {
    my $chan = $ssh2->channel();
    $chan->exec("monitor interface  xx.xx"); 
    $chan->exec("q"); ### This is not working 
    my $buflen = 100000;
    my $buf = '0' x $buflen;
    $chan->read($buf, $buflen);
    print "Starting: $buf ::Ending ";
}
```

I need to send the quit command (exec("q")) in the same channel for to interrupt(stop) the "monitor interface xxxx" command execution, since it run continuously. Someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can only execute one `exec` call on a channel.

I believe you are trying to feed input to the `monitor interface  xx.xx` program that you `exec`ed.  If so, you should:

```
$chan->write("q\n");
```